# Taxonomy formatter that shows a list of links to related nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a Taxonomy field on a Node. In the display of the node, I'd like a list of links to other related nodes, *not* a link to the Taxonomy category.

Is it best to build or find a formatter that can do this?

[image]

Or, is it best to make a View, and if so, what is the proper way to enforce the relationship between the selected Taxonomy Term item in the Node and the View?

Update: I found another StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367731/151957). Though seemingly complex (I don't yet understand how it works), the initial results are promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up a contextual filter on the View Block to `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`.

[image]

So we need to hand this view a term ID. Since we're going to be calling this block using Context. There won't be a default value given in the URL. Therefore we have to give it one.

Select

- `Provide Default Value`
- `Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks`
- Choose your default vocabulary

[image]

Comment: I would also add a Contextual filter on Node ID, and under 'provide default value' select 'Node ID forom URL', then under 'More' check to exclude. That way the current node will not appear in the list of similar nodes and you prevent the page linking to itself. Nice answer.